# How can i use the Keydown function in a textfield?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have a Textbox that shows me all the ADUsers. I want to be able to search these Users in a textfield. So that when I type in the textfield and press for example "tab" the right User Account appears. I have a working Keydown function, but its pretty far away from what I want. Could someone help me out with this?

This is my Powershell Script::

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

#GUI Interface
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400)
$Form.Text = "Benutzer Löschen"

#-----Labels-----
#Label Benutzer Löschen
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,10) 
$Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$Label.Text = "Benutzer Löschen"
$Label.Name = "Benutzer Löschen"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

#--------Buttons-------
#Button Cancel
$BTcancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BTcancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,200)
$BTcancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BTcancel.Text = "Cancel"
$BTcancel.Name = "Cancel"
$BTcancel.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($BTcancel)

#Button Löschen
$BTlöschen = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$BTlöschen.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,200)
$BTlöschen.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BTlöschen.Text = "Löschen"
$BTlöschen.Name = "Löschen"
$Form.Controls.Add($BTlöschen)

#-----ListBox-----
#User Anzeige
$Useranzeige = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$Useranzeige.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,50)
$Useranzeige.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100)
$Form.Controls.Add($Useranzeige)

#-----Textbox-----
#Suchfeld
$Suchfeld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$Suchfeld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,160) 
$Suchfeld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Suchfeld)

#---Funktionen---
#Useranzeige
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
        $name = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like '*'}
           foreach ($i in $name) 
           {$Useranzeige.Items.Add($i.Name + "`t")}

#BTlöschen
$BTlöschen.Add_Click({
Remove-ADUser -Identity $Suchfeld.Text
})

#Clear Inhalt vom Suchfeld
$BTlöschen.Add_Click{$Suchfeld.Clear()}

#Search Funkion
$Suchfeld.Add_KeyDown({
if ($_.Control -and $_.KeyCode -eq "F") {
        $stringToFind = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Find what", "Find")
        $pos = $Useranzeige.Text.IndexOf($stringToFind);
        if ($pos -ne -1) { 
            $Useranzeige.SelectionStart = $pos;
            $Useranzeige.SelectionLength = $stringToFind.Length;
        }
    } 
}) 
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is it that you need help with?

Comment: When I enter something in the Textfield it should show me the right user. Example: User: Sebastian Daniel 
I enter Seb. Now it should give me automatically the user sebastian daniel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue seems to be that you're trying to search through the `Text` property of a `ListBox` - this will be empty.

Go through the list of Items instead to find a matching name:

```
$Suchfeld.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.Control -and $_.KeyCode -eq "F") {
        $stringToFind = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Find what", "Find")
        for($Index = 0; $Index -lt $Useranzeige.Items.Count; $Index++){
            $pos = "$($Useranzeige.Items[$Index])".IndexOf($stringToFind, [System.StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            if($pos -eq -1){
                continue
            }
            $Useranzeige.SetSelected($Index,$true)
        }
    } 
})
```

Comment: Nice Answer. Kinda makes sense. Sadly it still doesen't work. Is it possible that it just doesent work cause its a textfield?. Because it still works when i try to search it in the listbox

Comment: Ahh, you want to `$Suchfield` control to autocomplete rather than use the `InputBox()`? Completely missed that part. Should be easy enough, just change the outer `if` statement and set `$stringToFind` to the value of `$Suchfeld.Text`

Comment: Yes exactly. Uhhh can you please edit your answer i am to nooby to understand the answer itself. LIke I literally don't understand half of the statement(still learning)^^

Comment: What do i need to change in the if statment?  if ($_.Control -and $_.KeyCode -eq "F") {
        $stringToFind = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::TextBox("Find what", "Find")